# Progressbar foreground color

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

Does anybody know how to change the foreground color of a WPF-Progressbar. It always seems to be merged with green.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is hard coded in default style:

```
<Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate"
     Value="false">
<Setter TargetName="Animation"
    Property="Background"
    Value="#80B5FFA9"/>
```

You can create your own style from original XAML or try to override background in the Loaded event for example:

```
private void ProgressBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var p = (ProgressBar)sender;
    p.ApplyTemplate();

    ((Panel)p.Template.FindName("Animation", p)).Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

but it's unreliable

Comment: Your snippet works. Why is not reliable?. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, the best option its to edit the progressbar template with the Expression Blend, but your snippet for codebehind its very usefull for testing and quick develop. (IMHO)

Comment: This solution works with Aero theme. You should check other themes to be sure that element named Animation exists there. And of course this problem may appear with custom templates.

Another trouble is theme switching. I don't know whether WPF reloads controls when the user changing OS theme. If not, then you need to handle this moment and change Animation's background again. If you don't want to provide your own template, I think it will be nice to derive from ProgressBar. There you should override OnApplyTemplate to resolve template bug everytime when template is changing.

Answer (score 27):

just try with this

```
   <ProgressBar Height="25" IsIndeterminate="True" Width="150" Foreground="Red" ></ProgressBar>
```

If it is not working as you required you have to modify the Style or ControlTemplate of Progressbar.

To do that you can use Expression Blend from Microsoft or you can get a copy the existing template and modify it.

Comment: You are right, editing the progressbar template with the expression Blend its the best option. Thaks for aswering.

Comment: Not sure what Expression Blend adds to the equation, but for simple color changes, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Why not take a path of low resistance and use the popular [MahApps](http://mahapps.com/) library?

1. Get the MahApps library:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/MahApps.Metro
2. Setup the namespace: `xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"`
3. Add the 'MetroProgressBar'

   ```
                   <controls:MetroProgressBar Height="40"
                                          Background="{StaticResource GrayBrush2}"
                                          BorderBrush="{StaticResource GrayBrush8}"
                                          BorderThickness="3"
                                          Foreground="{StaticResource GrayBrush8}"
                                          IsIndeterminate="False"
                                          Value="{Binding CurrentProgressInfo.ProgressPercent}" />
   ```
4. Set the 'Foreground' to your favorite color

Answer (score 3):

Marat Khasanov pointed out that the unwanted green tint comes from the object named "Animation" within the control template.  So another easy approach is to hide that object.  This will also disable the animated "glow" effect, which I considered to be an asset but you might see as a deal-killer.  I implemented this through a handler for the Loaded event as shown below.

This was inspired by [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6940736/2998072).  The same caveat applies: if they change the control template then this might no longer work.

```
    public void ProgressBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var progressBar = sender as ProgressBar;
        if (progressBar == null) return;

        var animation = progressBar.Template.FindName("Animation", progressBar) as FrameworkElement;
        if (animation != null)
            animation.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue when the Windows visual settings were optimised for best performance (Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Performance -> Settings -> Visual Effects -> Adjust for best performance). The progress bar looked fine under normal settings, but horrible under "best performance". I just changed ForeGround to "LightGreen".

Here's what I saw on default ForeColor under normal conditions

[image]

Here's what I saw when adjusted for best performance

[image]

Here is the change

```
//before
<ProgressBar Name="Progress" Grid.Column="0" Value="{Binding ProgressValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

//after
<ProgressBar Foreground="LightGreen" Name="Progress" Grid.Column="0" Value="{Binding ProgressValue}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Here's what I saw after when adjusted for best performance

[image]

Some more detail:
http://justmycode.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/the-case-of-strangely-coloured.html

Answer (score 1):

I found it rather useful to override the entire style.
You can pull the control template styles of any control with

```
var yourcontrol = new ProgressBar();
// the control needs to load before it has a template.
yourcontrol.Loaded += (sender,e) => {
    var str = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter(str))
        System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(yourcontrol .Template, writer);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(str);
};
// add it to your main grid, or some control thats loaded on screen.
gridMain.Children.Add(yourcontrol);
```

The progress style (with some formatting) comes out as the following:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="templateprogress"
                     TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Grid Name="TemplateRoot"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.Resources>

                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="0,1"
                                     x:Key="brushMagic1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#50FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.5385" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.5385" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="0,1"
                                     x:Key="brushMagic2">
                    <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.05" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.25" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="1,0"
                                     x:Key="brushGlowRect">
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.4" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.6" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="1,0"
                                     x:Key="brushLeftDark">
                    <GradientStop Color="#0C000000"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#20000000"
                                  Offset="0.3" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000"
                                  Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="1,0"
                                     x:Key="brushRightDark">
                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#20000000"
                                  Offset="0.7" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#0C000000"
                                  Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="1"
                                     RadiusY="1"
                                     x:Key="brushRadialLeftLight"
                                     RelativeTransform="1,0,0,1,0.5,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4"
                                  Offset="1" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1"
                                     EndPoint="0,0"
                                     x:Key="brushCenterLight">
                    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4"
                                  Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="1"
                                     RadiusY="1"
                                     x:Key="brushRadial1"
                                     RelativeTransform="1,0,0,1,-0.5,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Color="#60FFFFC4"
                                  Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFC4"
                                  Offset="1" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="0,1"
                                     x:Key="brushHighlight1">
                    <GradientStop Color="#90FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.5385" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.5385" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="0,1"
                                     x:Key="brushHighlight2">
                    <GradientStop Color="#80FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.05" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF"
                                  Offset="0.25" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Rectangle RadiusX="2"
                       RadiusY="2"
                       Fill="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" />
            <Border CornerRadius="2,2,2,2"
                    Margin="1,1,1,1"
                    Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushMagic1}" />
            <Border BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                    BorderBrush="#80FFFFFF"
                    Margin="1,1,1,1"
                    Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushMagic2}" />
            <Rectangle Name="PART_Track"
                       Margin="1,1,1,1" />
            <Decorator Name="PART_Indicator"
                       Margin="1,1,1,1"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Grid Name="Foreground">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding TextElement.Foreground}"
                               Name="Indicator" />
                    <Grid Name="Animation"
                          ClipToBounds="True">
                        <Rectangle Name="PART_GlowRect"
                                   Width="100"
                                   Margin="-100,0,0,0"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushGlowRect}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Name="Overlay">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="15" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="15" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Name="LeftDark"
                                   Margin="1,1,0,1"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushLeftDark}" />
                        <Rectangle RadiusX="1"
                                   RadiusY="1"
                                   Name="RightDark"
                                   Margin="0,1,1,1"
                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushRightDark}" />
                        <Rectangle Name="LeftLight"
                                   Grid.Column="0"
                                   Grid.Row="2"
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushRadialLeftLight}" />
                        <Rectangle Name="CenterLight"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.Row="2"
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushCenterLight}" />
                        <Rectangle Name="RightLight"
                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                   Grid.Row="2"
                                   Fill="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushRadial1}" />
                        <Border Name="Highlight1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushHighlight1}" />
                        <Border Name="Highlight2"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=brushHighlight2}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Decorator>
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="2,2,2,2"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ProgressBar.Orientation"
                     Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.LayoutTransform"
                        TargetName="TemplateRoot">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                        TargetName="LeftDark"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                        TargetName="RightDark"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                        TargetName="LeftLight"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                        TargetName="CenterLight"
                        Value="Collapsed" />

                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                        TargetName="RightLight"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                        TargetName="Indicator"
                        Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate"
                     Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Panel.Background"
                        TargetName="Animation"
                        Value="#80B5FFA9" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Template"
                Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=templateprogress}" />
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use style and customize as per yours requirement

```
                        </Border>

                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                    <Border Background="White" Margin="40,0,0,0" Width="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Border>
                    <Border Background="White" Margin="80,0,0,0" Width="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Border>
                    <Border Background="White" Margin="120,0,0,0" Width="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Border>
                    <Border Background="White" Margin="160,0,0,0" Width="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourProgressBarName.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```