# Wrong Colors in WPF Progress Bar

Tags: .net, wpf, progress-bar

**EDIT:** I solved my issue...take a look at my answer. Correct if it's wrong. Thanks.

**Question:** For some reason it seems that the progress bar in a WPF app isn't showing the color I require.

Here's the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TaskbarProgressApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
        <TaskbarItemInfo />
    </Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar"
                     Margin="10"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Height="23" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="DarkRed">
        </ProgressBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Doesn't look like Dark Red to me...happens to every color :(

Any thoughts ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: Progressbar foreground color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734814/wpf-progressbar-foreground-color)

Comment: You might want to [edit the template from Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx) if you have it.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob but how do I edit/use the control templates ?? I don't have Expression Blend.

Comment: You can create, edit, and use control templates without it.  It just provides convenient features to look at the existing control templates that are automatically applied.  There is also a free tool for a similar purpose [described on this page, called Dump Control Template](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/essential-tools-for-the-wpf-novice/).

Comment: I solved my problem. Posted the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Merlyn Morgan-Graham and @CharithJ for pointing out the other question, I thought it was a different one when I read it.

I solved the problem and I wanted to share it.

I downloaded the Trial of MS Expression Blend and changed:

```
<Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Animation" Value="#80B5FFA9"/>
</Trigger>
```

To

```
<Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Animation" Value="#00000000"/>
</Trigger>
```

This gives the colors as they are:

Dark Red:

[image]

Even this works

```
<Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Animation" Value="#80B5FFA9"/>
</Trigger>
```

Doesn't change the progress bar but the colors are as they should be.

It's sad that there is no option to change it directly.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by changing the control template. Here is an article on that from MSDN. [ProgressBar ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750638%28VS.100%29.aspx)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734814/wpf-progressbar-foreground-color) is another similar thread.

Comment: Thanks, but can you point out what exactly is going on with the colors ? I'm quite new at WPF so would like to know more.

Comment: @ Anon : I know that this can be done by using ComtrolTemplates. But cannot remember the exact steps. I also will have to go through the msdn examples.