# Changing the visual style of a progress bar C#. To Error State?

Tags: c#, colors, progress-bar

I'm writing a little game on a windows form in C#
Its pretty much done, its just about tidying up and making things looks nice.

I would like my health progressbar to change to red (Error State?) when health goes below 25

Its just that change of colour I need.

Thank you.

Comment: What control are you using?

Comment: Progress Bar C# Windows 7

Comment: Which control? There are many progress bars. Be precise.

Comment: Progress Bar Version 4.5 .NET component System.Windows.ProgressBar

Comment: Do you mean this: System.Windows.Controls.ProgressBar?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734814/wpf-progressbar-foreground-color

Comment: Yes, My apologies. I honestly didn't even know there were more than one

Comment: Well if this is the only way of changing the colour to the 'Error Red' State of a progress bar. Then i guess so... I would have thought there was a property that i could change?

Comment: I'm not expert in WPF, but I think that's how it goes in WPF. Now, in WinForms, it would be different .....