# C# Progressbar is not updated accurately in Vista or Windows7

Tags: c#, progress-bar

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  //....
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (this.progressBar1.Value >= 100)
     {
         this.timer1.Stop();
         this.timer1.Enabled = false;
     }
     else
     {
         this.progressBar1.Value += 10;
         this.label1.Text = Convert.ToString(this.progressBar1.Value);                
     }
  }
  //......
}
```

Here I used a timer to update the progress bar value. It works fine in XP. But in Windows7 or Vista when the progress value is set to say 100 but the graphical progress is not 100!

Searching some threads found that its for animation lag in Vista/Windows7.

How to get rid of this thing?

I don't want to loose the look and feel of Vista/Window7 using:

```
SetWindowTheme(progressBar1.Handle, " ", " ");
```

Comment: What are you seeing instead? It works as expected for me...

Comment: The label showing the progress = 100% that is finished! But the progress bar still seems 80% or 90%. Not what we want, right?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Windows Forms here (since there is no Dispatcher reference in your code) and I must agree with codeka, it works like a charm here...

We will need more details

Comment: @TimothyP: I have seen this behavior 100's of times. So unless you have never used WinForms on Vista or later, you would not have noticed.

Comment: Well iv seen this a few time also and it happens alot when the progress goes fast from 0% to 100% under a second or so......

Comment: I'm on a Windows 7 64 bit system.
But I haven't used Windows Forms in years... been doing WPF mostly... 
What happens if you break on progressBar1.Value += 10; does it get executed the last time as well?

Comment: Maybe you should use DoEvents after increasing the value ?

Comment: @TimothyP: Yes its Windows Forms, you can check the updated code now.

Comment: @Shimrod: Application.DoEvents() after increasing the value doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  //....
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.progressBar1.Value >= 100)
    {
     this.timer1.Stop();
     this.timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
      int tempValue = this.progressBar1.Value + 10;
      if (tempValue < 100 && tempValue >=0 )
      {
       this.progressBar1.Value = tempValue + 1;
       this.progressBar1.Value = tempValue;
      }
      else if (tempValue >= 100)
      {
       this.progressBar1.Value = 100;
       this.progressBar1.Value = 99;
       this.progressBar1.Value = 100;
      }
     this.label1.Text = Convert.ToString(this.progressBar1.Value);                
    }
  }

//......
}
```

The else part makes the progress bar looks OK now. But there should have been some standard way for progress bars. The idea is from from Fozi's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217688/windows-7-aero-theme-progress-bar-bug)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Fozi's tipps was helping me. The solution from Samir will work fine unless the maximum (100%). To make this work also for 100% the maximum must be increased before. The following worked fine for me.

```
if (NewValue < progressBar.Maximum)
{
  progressBar.Value = NewValue + 1;
  progressBar.Value--;
}
else
{
  progressBar.Maximum++;
  progressBar.Value = progressBar.Maximum;
  progressBar.Value--;
  progressBar.Maximum--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just how the stupid progress bars work in Vista and later.

There is no fix.

Complain to Microsoft.

Comment: I think they downvoted your comments is neither helpfull, insightfull or respectfull

If there is indeed such a bug, the devs @ microsoft would probably help if you new who to contact. I just tested this on windows 7 works, like a charm

Comment: @TimothyP -- no there _is_ lag... ie, the progress bar update is behind real time.  If the value is updating slowly, its fine, but if the value is updating quickly, the bar gets way behind.

Answer (score 1):

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (progressBar1.Maximum == 1) progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        if (progressBar1.Value==100) {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            return;
        }
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
        if (progressBar1.Value == 100) {
            progressBar1.Value = 1; progressBar1.Maximum = 1;
            progressBar1.Update();
        }
    }
```

These are my tricks to tackle the win7 problem with proper full scale paint of the progressbar.