# Cannot implement meter in windows API

Tags: c++, windows, api, progress, meter

I am using the windows API (in C++) to create a windows application.

Now, I have a progress bar which I want to show like a meter. A meter is blue and has no animation. I cannot figure out how to implement this, and if I have to, I will just settle for the usual green progress bar.

Please help.

EDIT: At least, is it possible to disable the animation (highlight the slides across the filled section of the bar)?

EDIT2:

Here is the C++ solution if anyone else is having this problem:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
RECT r;
HTHEME theme = OpenThemeData(hwnd,L"PROGRESS");
SetRect(&r,10,10,100,25);
DrawThemeBackground(theme,hDC,11,2,&r,NULL);
SetRect(&r,10,10,50,25);
DrawThemeBackground(theme,hDC,5,4,&r,NULL);
CloseThemeData(theme);
EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
```

Comment: You are leaking the handle, use CloseThemeData().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw this style of progress bar with DrawThemeBackground().  You'll find the theme name, part and state numbers in my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671366).

Comment: The return value of OpenThemeData().  The class name is "PROGRESS".

Answer (score 0):

The built in control cannot do this... however, it's not like ProgressBar is a complicated control. If you want nothing but a blue rectangle, use `DrawRect` and draw a blue rectangle.

Comment: it talks about meters in the msdn user expirience guide, but says nothing about its implementation.

Comment: @Alexander: I don't understand. If all you want is a rectangle, why do you need to make it more complicated. Am I missing something here?

Comment: it should look like a proper windows progress bar, but blue (and no animated). I'm fine using the green one, but it would be nice if someone knew how to get it like a meter (e.g. available disk space on my computer)

Comment: The progress bar's appearance depends on the particular operating system and theme.  If you want it to look different, you will have to use a custom control.