# How to get Windows 7 aero selection color?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, drawing, aero

How can I retreive system colors related to current Aero style? I especially need the colors used in the selection gradient. `SystemColors` structure does not contain required colors.

[image: Aero colors]

**Alternatively**: How can I use WinAPI to draw selection on the specific canvas (Graphics object)?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with a selection.  The way to draw this progress bar is shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2671848/17034

Comment: I don't really care about the progressbar, however I do care about the selection rectangle, as I stated in question. The VisualStyles is what I'm searching for, however I've got some trouble while using them, but I'll describe it in another question.

Comment: Shame, that you answer questions in comments, I cannot accept them.

Comment: Okay, you are talking about the pale blue background.  That's the selection color for a ListView in tile mode, switched to the "EXPLORER" visual style with SetWindowTheme().  This is all rather distant from what you seem to want to do.  You can post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: The truth is, that I've tried to draw the treeview item's selection, but on the way I noticed, that listview has the same kind of selection. A little bit around, I admit, I would rather draw the original treeview's selection, if possible. I usually write and accept answers myself, but it seems unfair, as these are not my solutions :)

Comment: Can you tell me, what do you mean by "EXPLORER" visual style? Maybe you know how to access the renderer for treeview or listview selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the answer to the initial question is: there is no way to determine the specific colors I asked for. It is evaluated by internal theming routines provided by the OS.

Fortunately, there is a way to ask the OS to draw a themed piece of control, so called part. .NET provides two classes for drawing UI:

- [System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.aspx) for themed UI and
- [System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.aspx) for non-themed "Windows Classic".

Selection I asked for may be drawn by the following code:

```
// Graphics g = ...
VisualStyleRenderer selectionRenderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.TreeView.Item.Selected);
selectionRenderer.DrawBackground(g, someRectangle);
```

Unfortunately, neither `TreeView.Item.Selected`, nor `ListView.Item.Selected` is supported by the default window theme. However, one may switch theme to the Explorer using WinAPI via p/invoke:

```
// C++
SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L"Explorer", nullptr);
```

And then P/invoke his way through few UXTheme.h routines, which works perfectly.

Comment: I know that, I asked another question regarding this matter. I guess, that some additional conditions shall be met to use these parts and states. However, I think, that this way is the best to follow, if one wishes to draw default UI parts.

Answer (score 0):

The system-defined color of the background of the selected items which includes the selected text and selected menu items as well is located at `System.Drawing.KnownColor.Highlight`

You may then use the `Color` struct to get a color from a `KnownColor`

**Example**

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(System.Drawing.KnownColor.Highlight);
```

Thanks,

Happy Holidays! :)

Comment: The Highlight in KnownColor is the same color, as SystemColors.Highlight and defines the color of a highlight, when the visual styles are disabled (as in Windows Classic style). This is not what I'm searching for.